# How to make all objects have different distanceInMeters?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

Thank you for coming here.

The problem is that all cells coming with only one distanceInMeters, all 100 objects have the same coordinates. How to fix it?

Thank you for your help!

```
func locationManager(_  manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{


    let currentLocation = locations[0]
    let coords = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    if (currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 ) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }


}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
    let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: mall.image)
    cell.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.nameLabel.text = mall.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = mall.location
    cell.typeLabel.text = mall.time
    let coords = CLLocation()
    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: malls[0].latitude, longitude: malls[0].longitude)

    let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords)
    let distanceInMetersString = String(distanceInMeters)

    cell.distanceLabel.text = distanceInMetersString

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems in your `cellForRowAt` method.

1. `coords` is an empty `CLLocation`, not the user's current location. You should store the user's current location in a property and use that property instead of the `coords` local variable.
2. You use `malls[0]` instead of `mall` to create `mallLocate`. This is why all 100 objects appear to have the same coordinates.

Comment: how to store the user's current location in a property and use that property instead of the coords local variable? thank you, really(

Comment: If you don't know how to use a property in Swift then you need to go straight to the [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) section of "The Swift Programming Language" book. Be sure to read the whole book after that.